# Change background color of Notepad++ Light Explorer plugin?

Tags: notepad++

I am looking for an option to change the background and font colors of The notepad++ "light explorer" plugin.

Is this possible at all?

And if so, how?

Comment: I suspect that is using whatever settings you have set for Windows Explorer.

Comment: What happens if you change style using Settings > Style Configurator? Does the color change?